# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module showsApp due to: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to set up a modal but I keep getting this error.

```
var showsApp = angular.module('showsApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'],['ui.bootstrap']);

showsApp.controller('ShowsController',  ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, $uibModal, $log, $document)
{
   var $ctrl = this;
}]);

<div ng-app='showsApp' ng-controller='ShowsController as $ctrl' class='modal'>

<script src='js/angular/angular.js'></script>
<script src='js/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/angular/angular-route.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js'></script>
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js'></script>
```

I am following this plunker to set it up https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview which I found on the angular site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change

```
var showsApp = angular.module('showsApp', 
        ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'],['ui.bootstrap']);
```

**To**

```
var showsApp = angular.module('showsApp', 
          ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','ui.bootstrap']);
```

**and also**

```
 showsApp.controller('ShowsController',  ['$scope', '$http', 
        function($scope, $http, $uibModal, $log, $document)
```

**To**

```
 showsApp.controller('ShowsController',  ['$scope', '$http','$uibModal',
               '$log', '$document', function($scope, $http, $uibModal, $log, $document)
```